# PHP Replace attribute single quotes with double quotes

Tags: php, html

The geniuses at Hotmail decided to mix single `'` and double quotes `"` for attributes in HTML emails for the lulz. This unnecessarily over-complicates things as I'm trying to get the class and id for the body element in some cases to remove it from CSS selectors. Doing a basic string replacement is obviously not an option here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that PHP's DOMDocument class does this automatically...

```
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //use this to prevent warning messages from displaying because of the bad HTML
 $html = new DOMDocument();//'1.0','UTF-8'
 $html->xmlStandalone = false;
 $html->loadHTML($b);
 $b = $html->saveXML();
```